# How to convert a Markdown file to PDF

Tags: pdf, markdown, pandoc

I have a Markdown file that I wish to convert to PDF so that I can upload it on Speakerdeck. I am using Pandoc to convert from markdown to PDF.

My problem is I can't specify what content should go on what page of the PDF, because Markdown doesn't provide any feature like that.

E.g., Markdown:

```
###Hello
* abc
* def

###Bye
* ghi
* jkl
```

Now I want `Hello` to be one slide and `Bye` to be on another slide on Speakerdeck. So, I will need them to be on different pages in the PDF that I generate using Pandoc.

But both `Hello` and `Bye` gets on the same page in the PDF.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: try using gimli ruby gem. its quite easy, for reference see http://blog.kushdilip.com/2014/02/convert-emberjs-online-guide-using.html

Comment: For future readers, they may want to check out https://github.com/alanshaw/markdown-pdf

Answer (score 236):

### Via the terminal (tested in 2020)

#### Download dependencies

```bash
sudo apt-get install pandoc texlive-latex-base texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-extra-utils texlive-latex-extra
```

#### Try to use

```bash
pandoc MANUAL.txt -o example13.pdf
pandoc MANUAL.md -o example13.pdf
```

### Via a Visual Studio Code extension (tested in 2020)

- Download the [Yzane Markdown PDF](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzane.markdown-pdf) extension
- Right click inside a Markdown file (`md`)
- The content below will appear
- Select the `Markdown PDF: Export (pdf)` option

[image: Visual Studio Code Markdown PDF]

Comment: On Debian, after installing those dependencies and running the command above (using a `.md` instead of a `.txt` file, however), I get an error: `File 'letltxmacro.sty' not found.` - despite that file apparently being part of `texlive-latex-base`. Would you have any idea on why that happens?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea :/

Comment: @domsson I had the same problem. Installing `texlive-latex-extra` solved it.

Comment: We've been over this: Excessive emoji are _unnecessary and distracting_. Most of the ones that were in this answer are poorly-chosen and don't add any value. You will note that [an 800k+ reputation moderator removed emoji from one of your posts a couple of weeks ago](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57834015/revisions). This should be a sign that overuse of emoji is not welcome. **Please don't replace them.**

Comment: This answer also fixed an issue I was having on my side: `! LaTeX Error: File \`booktabs.sty' not found.`

Comment: In a debian:10 docker image, this tries to install 1GB of dependencies, all that just to convert a few kilobytes of Markdown into PDF. I wonder if there is a solution that involves a bit less overhead.

Comment: Note: For me the second solution only worked after restarting VSCode

Comment: _The Linux OS doesn't support emojis well (Windows is better)_ -- I doubt it's the duty of operating systems to support emojis. I guess it's about applications.

Comment: The answer rocks! it works well with images and code snippets unlike the other alternatives.

Comment: Installation on Windows can be done by executing the `choco install rsvg-convert python miktex` and the `choco install pandoc` commands. Reference: https://pandoc.org/installing.html#windows

Answer (score 77):

2016 update:

NPM module: https://github.com/alanshaw/markdown-pdf

Has a command line interface: https://github.com/alanshaw/markdown-pdf#usage

```
npm install -g markdown-pdf
markdown-pdf <markdown-file-path>
```

Or, an online service: http://markdown2pdf.com

Comment: using the online service, I keep getting `Error generating PDF.`

Comment: The online service seems broken now.

Comment: @ÁrpádMagosányi well, I use it on Ubuntu.  be specific what doesn't work.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 19.04 command line. A few event related warnings, but produces a correct pdf.

Comment: I tested it, tables don't seem to have separating lines in the output PDF

Comment: If you don't want to install the tool, you can do it with npx:

npx markdown-pdf <mardkown-file-path>

Comment: unfortunately markdown-pdf seems to be dead and doesn't work either on current Ubuntu nor on current Debian systems as of 2021-09-01, see [here](https://github.com/alanshaw/markdown-pdf/issues/194)

Comment: Now the website is back online, but the output is not perfect: in my test the list markers were not in the same line as the items and "_italic_" between quotes wasn't recognized.

Answer (score 45):

As SpeakerDeck only accepts PDF files, the easiest option is to use the [Latex Beamer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamer_%28LaTeX%29) backend for `pandoc`:

```
pandoc -t beamer -o output.pdf yourInput.mkd
```

Note that you should have LaTeX Beamer installed for that.

In Ubuntu, you can do `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended` to install it. If you use Windows, you may [try this answer](http://kenjokenjo.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/how-to-install-latex-and-beamereasy/).

You may also want to try the HTML/CSS output from Slidy:

```
pandoc --self-contained -t slidy -o output-slidy.html yourInput.mkd
```

It has a decent printing output, as you can check out [trying to print the original](http://www.w3.org/Talks/Tools/Slidy2/Overview.html).

Read [more about slideshows with pandoc here](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/example9/producing-slide-shows-with-pandoc.html).

Comment: `pandoc -t beamer -o output.pdf yourInput.mkd` produces only one pdf page. Extra contents are cut.

Comment: @alhelal Same issue here. Any hints?

Comment: @rkioji Try the tip from the other answer, add `***` where you want to break a page.

Comment: To install the dependencies on Fedora: `sudo dnf install -y pandoc texlive-beamer texlive-ec
`

Comment: Last link johnmacfarlane.net is dead. The domain probably does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 21):

Easy online solution: [dillinger.io](https://dillinger.io/).

Just paste your Markdown content into the editor on the left and see the (`html`) preview on the right. Then click `Export as` on the top and chose `pdf`.

It's based on the [open source](https://github.com/joemccann/dillinger) dillinger editor.

Comment: `pandoc` errored out on me, because of "too nested" lists (was trying to print an outliner export), dillinger worked, thanks!

Comment: dillinger.io renders HTML tags as text in tables, eg. `b<sub>7</sub> | b<sub>6</sub> | etc...` does not display subscript in the HTML preview, but funnily enough the PDF output is correct, so thanks from me also!

Answer (score 7):

Adding to [elias' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630486/how-to-convert-from-a-markdown-file-to-pdf/17631113#17631113), if you want to separate text in slides, just put `***` between the text you want to separate. For your example to be in several pages, write it like this:

```
### Hello
- abc
- def

***

### Bye
- ghi
- jkl
```

And then use elias' answer, `pandoc -t beamer -o output.pdf yourInput.md`.

I have [Ubuntu 18.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.10_(Cosmic_Cuttlefish)) (Cosmic Cuttlefish) and installed the full package from texlive. It works for me.

Answer (score 6):

Previously I had used the npm markdown-pdf answer. However, on a fresh install of [Ubuntu 19.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.04_(Disco_Dingo)) (Disco Dingo) I had issues getting it to install correctly.

Instead I started using the Visual Studio Code package: "Markdown PDF"

Details: 
Name: Markdown PDF 
Id: yzane.markdown-pdf 
Description: Convert Markdown to PDF 
Version: 1.2.0 
Publisher: yzane 
Visual Studio Marketplace link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzane.markdown-pdf

It has worked consistently well. If you've had issues getting other answers to work, I would recommend trying this.

Comment: I've just done this on both Windows and Linux. Installation was a breeze in both cases, and worked well without any configuration or setup.

Answer (score 6):

I found that many markdown-to-pdf converters produce files that I don't find exactly neat-looking. However there is a solution to this.

If you're using IntelliJ, you can use a plugin called "Markdown". The export  function uses `pandoc` as an engine so you probably will need to install that along with pdf-latex. https://pandoc.org/installing.html

**In IntelliJ, under Tools > Markdown Converter > Export Markdown File To...**

And there you go, a clean looking document. Additional styling can be added via a `.css` stylesheet.

Answer (score 4):

I've managed to get a stable Markdown -> HTML > PDF pipeline working with the [MarkReport](https://github.com/rginestou/MarkReport) project.

It is a bit more than what Pandoc will do though, since it is based on [WeasyPrint](https://weasyprint.org/) and is therefore aimed for clean report publishing, with cover, headers, sections, ...
It also enriches the HTML with syntax highlighting and LaTeX equations.

Comment: Minor note: pandoc can export via WeasyPrint, too. (Useful, e.g., when targeting HTML from a document containing citations).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using [mdtopdf](https://github.com/mandolyte/mdtopdf).
It supports syntax highlighting, paging and dark and light themes.

Install md2pdf by obtaining the [release](https://github.com/mandolyte/mdtopdf/releases) for your arch and OS or, if you have go installed, invoke:

```bash
$ go install github.com/mandolyte/mdtopdf/cmd/md2pdf@latest
```

If you require syntax highlighting, download the [gohighlight lexers](https://github.com/jessp01/gohighlight/tree/master/syntax_files)

`md2pdf` supports all major markdown features and accepts local files, remote HTTP(s) URL and STDIN inputs. The below command will convert a markdown file to a PDF with a dark theme, syntax highlighting (you'll need to provide the language hint, of course), page/slide separation and a footer:

```bash
md2pdf -i https://github.com/jessp01/crash-course-in/raw/main/courses/apt_dpkg_deb/apt_dpkg_deb.md \
    -o apt_dpkg_deb.pdf \
    -s ~/.config/zaje/syntax_files \
    --theme dark \
    --new-page-on-hr \
    --with-footer \
    --author "Jesse Portnoy <jesse@packaman.io>" \
    --title "A crash course on handling deb packages"
```

Answer (score 2):

With [python script](https://github.com/vb64/markdown-pdf):

```
pip install markdown-pdf

from markdown_pdf import Section, MarkdownPdf

pdf = MarkdownPdf()
# each section starts from new page in pdf file
pdf.add_section(Section("###Hello\n* abc\n* def\n"))  # page 1
pdf.add_section(Section("###Bye\n* ghi\n* jkl\n"))  # page 2
pdf.save("out.pdf")
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way with iOS:

Use Shortcuts app (by Apple)

Make Rich Text From Markdown: Clipboard

^

Make PDF from Rich Text From Markdown

^

Show [PDF] in Quick Look

Just copy text and run the shortcut. Press share in Quick Look (bottom left) to store or send it. I use this to quickly convert Joplin notes to pdf.

Answer (score 1):

## Using Okular

1. Make sure your file has the ".md" extension.
2. Open in [Okular](https://okular.kde.org/)
3. File -> Export As -> PDF -> Select save location and save.

## Using discount

To go the Markdown -> HTML -> PDF path, you can use the [discount](https://www.pell.portland.or.us/%7Eorc/Code/markdown/) package directly (Okular uses it)

1. Say your file is named "filename.md". Use `markdown filename.md > outfile.html` to get the html into an html file "outfile.html".
2. Use your preferred method of converting HTML to PDF.

- discount also has other binaries: `theme` and `makepage` - which you can check out for their specific features.

Answer (score 0):

Use the python `md2pdf` library with `weasyprint`.

```
pip install md2pdf weasyprint
```

Then convert your file

```
md2pdf inputfile.md outputfile.pdf
```

Want more control over formatting?  Grab some markdown css from here: https://github.com/sindresorhus/github-markdown-css

Then use:

```
md2pdf --css markdown.css inputfile.md outputfile.pdf
```